# JList repaint method at multi-threaded

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a program that checks every second in the database for newly inserted row and if a new record is found, I have to clear my listModel and retrieve all data again from the database and re-display it in the list.

```
    itemListModel.clear();

    ArrayList resultArrayList = DBQueries.getAllSubmittedSaleTransaction();
    Iterator iterate = resultArrayList.iterator();

    int i = 0;
    while (iterate.hasNext()) {
        Hashtable data = (Hashtable) iterate.next();            
        itemListModel.add(i, data);

        this.itemList.addNotify();
        this.itemList.validate();
        this.itemList.repaint();

        i++;
    }
    this.validate();
    this.repaint();
```

but, the problem is, the repaint method sometimes work sometimes not.
Is there any smart way to accomplish this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to repaint the JList if you are updating the model, especially if your model calls `fireContentsChanged(...)` after the new data has been added. Be sure to only change the model on the Swing event thread.

Consider that you

- Do the database query in a SwingWorker.
- Add a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker
- When the SwingWorker's state property is changed to `SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE`, have the GUI get the new data from the SwingWorker and populate the ListModel on the EDT
- And then have your ListModel fire its `fireContentChanged(...)` method.
- The ListModel should extend AbstractListModel.
- Note that if you're able to use a DefaultListModel, you don't even have to call the `fireContent....()` method since the DefaultListModel will do that for you.

Comment: +1, when I see the word "sometimes", I think GUI update code not being executed on the EDT.